# uuid_generate_v4 extension unavailable from command line

Tags: sql, postgresql, uuid

I have very strange behavior of `select uuid_generate_v4 ();` function

When I run select from pgadmin its working `select uuid_generate_v4 ();`
and return me UUID
[image]

When I run it from the command line its trowing error

```
select uuid_generate_v4 ();
ERROR:  function uuid_generate_v4() does not exist
LINE 1: select uuid_generate_v4 ();
               ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Have no idea why its happening and how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, the problem is I was running select in pgAdmin from the public schema, and in the command line, I run it from a specific schema by setting it

```
set search_path to my_schema;
```

The fix is to alter the extension and set it to proper schema

```
ALTER EXTENSION "uuid-ossp" SET SCHEMA my_schema;
```

Comment: WRONG SOLUTION. After your alter the all other users in their schema must must reference it by `my_schema.uuid_generate_v4()` . A better solution is to extend your search path by adding public. `SET search_path TO my_schema, public;` That is after you move "uuid-ossp"  back to public;

Comment: actually, because I am using set search_path to my_schema; I dont need to spesify schema, but then this function is not available from different schemas :(

Comment: Correct, as long everybody in the database uses that same schema (my_schema), now and for the life of the system. then they do not either.  Any user not in `my_schema` (including the user Postgres) must reference the function as `my_schema.uuid_generate_v4()`. And you must great permission.

Comment: I prefer to have my extensions in a different schema (`public`) than my application data. You can have two schemas on your `search_path`!